# NXLog with HTTPS: How to configure SSL and certificate?

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, lets-encrypt, nxlog

I'm trying to use NXLog to post to a service in https.
Unfortunately, I keep receiving this error for every post attempts:

`2018-12-19 09:11:14 ERROR SSL certificate verification failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (err: 20)`

The service we are trying to reach is an HTTPS endpoint with a "Let's encrypt" certificate. I have no problem posting to the endpoint with tools like Postman. But NXLog keeps complaining.

I tried to play with the multiple options of the https module but since I don't really understand what they are and the [documentation](https://nxlog.co/docs/nxlog-ce/nxlog-reference-manual.html#om_http_config) is not very helpful, I need help.

I tried to put `HTTPSAllowUntrusted` to `TRUE` but it doesn't change anything. Also tried to provide `.pem` file from mozilla and various source in `HTTPSCADir` and `HTTPSCAFile` but that doesn't change anything too.

Here is my latest `.conf` file attemps. Any help to be able to configure SSL would be welcome.

```
Panic Soft
#NoFreeOnExit TRUE

define ROOT     C:\Program Files (x86)\nxlog
define CERTDIR  %ROOT%\cert
define CONFDIR  %ROOT%\conf
define LOGDIR   %ROOT%\data
define LOGFILE  %LOGDIR%\nxlog.log
LogFile %LOGFILE%

Moduledir %ROOT%\modules
CacheDir  %ROOT%\data
Pidfile   %ROOT%\data\nxlog.pid
SpoolDir  %ROOT%\data

<Extension _syslog>
    Module      xm_syslog
</Extension>

<Extension _charconv>
    Module      xm_charconv
    AutodetectCharsets iso8859-2, utf-8, utf-16, utf-32
</Extension>

<Extension csv>
    Module xm_csv
    Fields $contentName, $deviceName, $startTime, $endTime, $contentId, $deviceId
    FieldTypes string, string, string, string, string, string
    Delimiter ,
</Extension>

<Extension exec>
    Module      xm_exec
</Extension>

<Extension json>
    Module  xm_json
</Extension>

<Input in>
    Module          im_file
    File            "C:\\MagicInfo Premium\\runtime\\upload\\pop\\report\\*W*.csv"
    Exec            csv->parse_csv(); to_json();
</Input>

<Output http>
    Module               om_http
    URL                  https://my-service.com/api/v1/proof-of-play-log/
    HTTPSCAFile          %CERTDIR%/cacert.pem
    ContentType          application/json
</Output>

<Route 1>
    Path            in => http
</Route>
```

To summarize: What .pem file do I need and what parameter needs to be set to do a simple post to an https endpoint that has a "Let's encrypt" certificate.

**EDIT**

Finally, I realised NXLog is completely buggy and badly coded so we changed to another solution...

Comment: What’s the site in question? I’ll take a look with the OpenSSL debugger. Also try putting the site into an online ssl checker. My guess is that they misconfigured the server by omitting the intermediary cert, but it works elsewhere because it’s a common intermediary the I already in the cache for tools like Postman that you’ve used on other sites.

Comment: Finally, I realised NXLog is completely buggy and badly coded so we changed to another solution...

Answer (score 1):

## The Intermediates May Be Missing

This is rare and may not be the solution to your problem, but it is a solution to some problems with exactly the same symptoms.

The untrusted very option may be failing because it may allow untrusted cert chains, but not orphaned / incomplete chains (which is slightly different). Though, on second thought, that’s probably not possible to distinguish...

But if it is the case, the extra certa you’d want to include are the intermediates listed in the “active”  and “backup” sections at https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/

Comment: Will give it a try. So just to be sure I understand. I put all these files in a folder and use the `HTTPSCADir` to indicate this folder?

Comment: Does the naming of the files have any effect? Do I need other configuration field in NXLog for this to work?